# Get Request and Return Value in a Function

Tags: javascript, function, get

For some reason, "p" returns as undefined. How would I make it return the array?

```
function doT() {
    var pe;
    $.get("https://www.google.com", function(data) { 
    pe = ["a", "b", "c"]; 
    });
    return pe;
}

var p = doT();
setTimeout(function() { console.log(p.length); }, 1200);
```

Comment: DoT doesn't return anything - why do you expect any result?

Comment: Now it does. I only put the setTimeout just in case the get request wasn't finished yet and it was returning the blank pe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I agree @AlexeiLevenkov Do you know how to fix it though? I'm not really following the responses too well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the ways will be to use [promise](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) (read about it):

Right now it goes to the reject block because of [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) (read about it):

```js
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  var pe;
  $.ajax("https://www.google.com")
    .done(function() {
      pe = ["a", "b", "c"];
      resolve(pe);
    })
    .fail(function() {
      reject("error");
    });
});
promise.then(function(result) {
  $("#testing").text(result);
}, function(err) {
  $("#testing").text(err);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="testing"></div>
```

Just make a valid ajax call and it will work. Comment if need further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
function doT() {

  var pe = $.get("https://www.google.com", function(data) { 
    pe = ["a", "b", "c"]; 
  });

 return pe;
}

alert(doT());
```

Comment: Did you test this?

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others